# existence of absolute value of function's improper Riemann integral implies existence of function's improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

The question:

Let $f$ be continuous over the reals such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx$ exists. Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ exists.

Would it be sufficient to go about this using the Triangle Inequality (i.e. $f(x) \leq |f(x)|$ over the entire integral?)

Not sure as to why this was marked off-topic. This is an important question about improper integration, and I presented my line of thought above. I urge those who find it off-topic to demonstrate why, as this is exactly how the question was presented to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. What you want to show is that 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx=0
$$ (and the analog case at $-\infty$). You achieve that by 
$$
\left|\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx\right|\leq\int_N^\infty|f(x)\,dx.
$$